# Log-normal vs. log-linear vs. logging the response variable

Tags: generalized-linear-model, terminology, lognormal-distribution, log-linear

I've been reading a lot of Wikipedia pages and StackExchange/CrossValidated posts, and I have come to a point where I realize I do not understand some of the terminology I have been using.

**What's the difference between *log-normal* models, *log-linear* models, and linear models that log the response?**

I have been running power simulations for reaction time data (RTs, which are not exactly log-normally distributed, but have definite skew), and testing the power of **models that are regressed on the *raw* RTs** (i.e. `glm(RT ~ predictors, family="gaussian")` in R) vs. **models that are regressed on the *logged* RTs** (i.e. `glm(log(RT) ~ predictors, family="gaussian")`).

I have been referring to the models regressed on `log(RT)` as **log-normal models**, as well as sometimes **log-linear**.  After this made some people I talked to confused, I realized I was unsure. They seemed to suggest that log-normal (or possibly log-linear models) were *multiplicative* models (in that `log(predictor_1) + log(predictor_2) = log(predictor_3)`). I don't believe that's what is happening in my models, since I'm never logging the predictors (in the log(RT) model, I was conceptualizing it as the predictors having linear effects on the RTs in log space).

For example [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/linear-model-with-log-transformed-response-vs-generalized-linear-model-with-log) clarified to me that I'm not taking the log of the mean, but taking the mean of the log.  Importantly, that suggests to me that I'm *not* changing the link function. However, I've heard what I'm doing basically the same thing. And then I've heard [log-linear models aren't the same as Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261946/log-linear-regression-vs-poission-regression), but Wikipedia seems to say otherwise.

What the heck is going on here?

Comment: One of the problems you're having there is that the term "log-linear model" is used in different contexts (to mean somewhat similar things).