# Fit exponential growth: should I fit the cumulative or incidents per day?

Tags: fitting, growth-model

Suppose we want to fit an exponential growth model on some disease outbreak, should we use the cumulative count or incidents per day count?

According to my understanding we should use the cumulative count, as in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446712/fitting-sir-model-with-2019-ncov-data-doesnt-conververge), But why the [source code of R0 package](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261946/log-linear-regression-vs-poisson-regression) is not using cumulative?